# Basic installation questions

Tags: installation

I've downloaded WordPress and I want to ensure I'm uploading it to my server correctly:

1. I see there's a .zip file and a .tar.gz file -- which should I use? It's an Apache server. This is the place my site will be: http://plowtoplate.com/
2. I want the site to be at http not at www., but I do want either the site to also be visible at www. or for the www. to redirect to http -- where should I upload the WordPress files? Into public_html? or just into the place I get to when I login with ftp? (the 'root' I think that's called...?)
3. Do I unzip wordpress-3.2.1.zip and upload those files, or do I upload the .zip to the server?
4. Once the files are uploaded, is there anything else to do before it's ready to go?
5. How do I get the username and password to login to the admin panel so I can build the site? And what url do I go to to login?

Beginner questions, I know.

I appreciate help.

Thanks, Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress Codex has quite extensive [installation instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress).

> I see there's a .zip file and a .tar.gz file -- which should I use?

No difference. Archive format is merely for convenience, contents are the same.

> I want the site to be at http not at www., but I do want either the site to also be visible at www. or for the www. to redirect to http -- where should I upload the WordPress files? Into public_html?

It depends on how your domain is set up, but usually both www and non-www version point to same thing. `public_html` is probably right directory.

You will only be able to pick www or non-www link when configuring WordPress. Redirecting other version will need a bit of `.htaccess` tweak, google it.

> Do I unzip wordpress-3.2.1.zip and upload those files, or do I upload the .zip to the server?

Depends on how comfortable you are with server-side manipulation. Uploading unpacked files is easier, uploading archive and unpacking on server (using SSH or cpanel for example) is faster.

Note that there is `wordpress` directory in archive which you don't need, files whould be unpacked to the root of the site.

> Once the files are uploaded, is there anything else to do before it's ready to go?

See link to Codex above, you should have database created, etc.

> How do I get the username and password to login to the admin panel so I can build the site? And what url do I go to to login?

Trying to visit site with freshly uploaded WordPress files will redirect you to `install.php` that will guide you through initial configuration. Initial setup should have link to admin area in theme sidebar, you can also always go there by visiting `/wp-admin/` URL.

Comment: thanks Rarst. I'll upload unpacked files. I asked above about whether to include the folder 'wordpress' or just the files in it. once I know that, sounds like I'll be good to go.

Comment: @Richard I covered that in my answer, you do not need `wordpress` folder (unless you want WP set up as `/wordpress/` which is rarely the case).

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the file on your computer and upload all the files to your public_html folder.

When that's done, just surf in to your site plowtoplate.com and continue the setup.. you will get to choose password etc.

You also need login information to you database, that info you probably got from your hosting.

you will be able to surf into your site through www and http.. but http will be default.

Comment: thanks. when I unzip, all the files are in a folder named 'wordpress' -- do i upload the folder 'wordpress', or just the files in that folder?

Comment: upload all the content in that folder to public_html.. if you upload the wordpress folder your blog will be at plowtoplate.com/wordpress